# Custom Product Image Label

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, image, labels

I am trying to get the image label of a custom product image attribute, i have added options but i am unable to get the label for each type.

[image]

The code i am using to pull the labels is

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'bundle_image_1')->resize(100) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getImageLabel($_item, 'bundle_image_1') ?>" class="float-left" />

<h4><?php echo $this->getImageLabel($_item, 'bundle_image_1') ?></h4>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code,try with this

```
    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
    $customimg = $product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('file',$product->getData('bundle_image_1'));
    if($customimg->getLabel()){
        echo $customimg->getLabel(); 
    }
```

Comment: welcome..... :)